# No tab headings in Magento 2 - product page

Tags: magento2.4.3

Not sure if anybody can help but I don't currently have any tabs for the reviews area and more information etc. I have a photo attached which shows what it looks like. I am quite new to Magento at the moment.
I am currently using a custom theme but it is also like it on the default Luma theme too.
How would I go about adding this back in?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this configuration and details

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-magento-2-tab/

hope it helps

Comment: I have just tried that to no avail. I have also just gone into the initial file (catalog_product view.xml) and it has the correct information
[Image of the tab code by default](https://ibb.co/gT5x484)
Just doesn't seem to be displaying it correctly